# When does a heap become a full binary tree?

Tags: tree, heap, binary-tree, binary-heap

I know that heaps are always complete binary trees. But I was wondering when is a heap a full binary tree? Such as what conditions must the heap be in to always be a full binary tree?

Answer (score 0):

To show why the heap condition is unimportant, consider that it is easily possible to give a labeling for *any* binary tree that fulfills the heap condition by simply assigning each node its height. (If you want unique labels, you can just topologically sort the tree and start counting from the root.)

Therefore completeness and fullness are orthogonal concepts for heaps as well (look [here](http://assets.openstudy.com/updates/attachments/4f873572e4b0505bf086cc69-jayanta-1334265117676-t03a.binarytreetheorems.pdf) for examples of trees that are complete, full, both and neither).

However, often heap implementations choose to ensure the heap condition in such a way that the resulting binary tree is complete. A standard way to implement a normal binary heap is to use an array and then fill it from left to right with an implicit binary heap (this is the way heapsort is usually implemented).

If this is the kind of heap you are referring to, the constraints tighten significantly, since you always fill the tree one level at a time from the left to the right. It should be obvious why such a tree is complete (all levels but the last are always completely filled).

It should also be easily seen that it always alternates between full and not full:

- if it has only the root, it is full.
- if you add a node to a full tree, necessarily its parent will have only one (left) child, and therefore the tree will not be full anymore.
- If your tree is not full anymore, the next insertion will make it full again, since it will be inserted as the (right) child of the parent you gave a left child to in the previous step.